# Something wrong with my crontab?

Tags: linux, centos, cron

I am going to create a `crontab` task to schedule my task.

My `/etc/crontab` looks like this,

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/
17 15 * * * root sh /opt/app/tool/ReviewSummaryTool/runf.sh
```

The task script `runf.sh` has content looks like this,

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

java -Dhostname=$(hostname) -jar ReviewSummaryTool.jar -full
```

But the crontab task could not be executed (I checked the output log) when time is arrived.

However, the task script could be execute by command below,

```
sh /opt/app/tool/ReviewSummaryTool/runf.sh
```

And I checked the log of `crontab` at `/var/log/cron` and it seems that the task has already been executed. See brief log content below,

```
Aug 31 15:17:01 SSECBIGDATA01 crond[1677]: (*system*) RELOAD (/etc/crontab)
Aug 31 15:17:01 SSECBIGDATA01 CROND[29248]: (root) CMD (sh /opt/app/tool/ReviewSummaryTool/runf.sh)
```

Now, I have no idea what's wrong with my configuration.  My operating system is CentOS.

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean, "the crontab task could not be executed ...", the `/var/log/cron` file shows it executed on 15:17:01.  Also, maybe `$(hostname)` is not set.

Comment: @RedCricket: `$(hostname)` is like a backquoted `hostname` command, giving the output of the command.

Comment: Red Cricket, sorry, I mean that my task is not executed.

Comment: `$(hostname)` works correctly. I have test it my self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging purposes replace `sh` with `/bin/sh -vx` in the `crontab` entry:

```
 17 15 * * * root /bin/sh -vx /opt/app/tool/ReviewSummaryTool/runf.sh
```

<sup>Then the trace of the executed script will be printed, so emailed to you.</sup>

And add `logger` commands inside your `runf.sh` script, e.g.  have it be

```
 #!/bin/sh
 logger -t runfjob start of runf pid $$ in $(pwd) on host $(hostname)
 java -Dhostname=$(hostname) -jar ReviewSummaryTool.jar -full
 logger -t runfjob end of runf pid $$
```

<sup>The `logger` command makes entries to the system log using `syslog(3)`.  You should find these messages under `/var/log`, perhaps in `/var/log/messages`  or `/var/log/syslog` etc...</sup>

I strongly suggest to put the full path of the `ReviewSummaryTool.jar` file in the `java` command of your `runf.sh` script. It is likely that your cronjob is run in a current directory not having that file. Or perhaps put a `cd` command before the `java` one.

Be sure that the `$PATH` is correct and that `java` is found there.

Comment: Greate advice helped me fixing it. Thanks.